# C# Error CS0508: Incorrect Return Type on overriding an abstract method

Tags: c#, xamarin

In my code I'm extending the following [class](https://github.com/dotnet-bluetooth-le/dotnet-bluetooth-le/blob/master/Source/Plugin.BLE/Shared/CharacteristicBase.cs). I have the following code and the override methods are even generated by Visual Studio 2022. However, I'm getting a CS0508, as the return type of the methods

- GetDescriptorsNativeAsync()
- ReadNativeAsync()
- WriteNativeAsync(...)
- StartUpdatesNativeAsync(...)
- StopUpdatesNativeAsync(...)

is incorrect. And I don't have a clue, why this is the case.

```
internal class SomeCharacteristic : CharacteristicBase<int>
    {
        public SomeCharacteristic(IService service) : base(service,0)
        {
        }

        public override Guid Id
        {

            get
            {
                return SomeChar.ToString();

            }

        }

        public override string Uuid
        {

            get
            {
                return SomeChar.ToString();

            }

        }

        public override byte[] Value => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override CharacteristicPropertyType Properties => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override event EventHandler<CharacteristicUpdatedEventArgs> ValueUpdated;

        protected override async Task<IReadOnlyList<IDescriptor>> GetDescriptorsNativeAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override Task<(byte[] data, int resultCode)> ReadNativeAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override Task<int> WriteNativeAsync(byte[] data, CharacteristicWriteType writeType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override Task StartUpdatesNativeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override Task StopUpdatesNativeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The error message I get is the following

```
 (awaitable) Task<IReadOnlyList<IDescriptor>> SomeCharacteristic.GetDescriptorsNativeAsync()

Native implementation of GetDescriptorsAsync.

CS0508: 'SomeCharacteristic.GetDescriptorsNativeAsync()': return type must be 'Task<IReadOnlyList<IDescriptor>>' to match overridden member 'CharacteristicBase<string>.GetDescriptorsNativeAsync()'
```

Here is a link to the [image: screenshot of the error message].

Comment: Please provide the *complete*, copy-pasted error message.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the hint. Added the Error Message to the Question. The error message is the same for the other methods as well.

Comment: Is "Native implementation of GetDescriptorsAsync" part of the error message? If not, where does that come in? That's not something I've seen before. (Perhaps it's Xamarin-specific.) If you remove one of the methods and type "override" and let VS provide the method declaration, do you get the same problem?

Comment: Are the IDescriptor and IReadOnlyList interfaces the exact same interfaces as the base class references? Maybe the IDescriptor you have in your return type is a different interface than the IDescriptor in the baseclass.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, it is part of the message. I added a link to the screen shot.

Comment: @yaba well, it looks like.  The method in the base class (linked) is ```protected abstract Task<IReadOnlyList<IDescriptor>> GetDescriptorsNativeAsync();```

Comment: Ah, no, that's *not* part of the error message. That's the XML documentation for the method. I suggest that you look in the list of error messages in the Errors section of Visual Studio rather than just the tooltip. I suspect it's the same error message as is shown at the bottom of the tooltip, but you never know, it might have more detail.

Comment: @JonSkeet so the error message is the same - BUT it looks like there is problem with the references (https://snipboard.io/qVAIPh.jpg). Let me look into that one first; maybe that is the root cause.

Comment: Okay, that may very well be the issue. I would remove your class for now, and get to the stage where everything else compiles without errors first.

Comment: the initital error was the problem. so this problem is solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by another error. so the question is obsolte.